# pandas outer product of two dataframes with same index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the following dataframes `d1` and `d1`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [3, 4, 5]
], columns=list('ABC'))

d2 = pd.get_dummies(list('XYZZXY'))
```

---

```
d1

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  1  2  3
4  2  3  4
5  3  4  5
```

---

```
d2

   X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  0  0  1
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  0
```

---

I need to get a new dataframe with a multi-index columns object that has the product of every combination of columns from `d1` and `d2`

---

So far I've done this...

```
from itertools import product
pd.concat({(x, y): d1[x] * d2[y] for x, y in product(d1, d2)}, axis=1)

   A        B        C      
   X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0  2  0  0  3  0  0
1  0  2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0
2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0  0  5
3  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  0  3
4  2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0  0
5  0  3  0  0  4  0  0  5  0
```

---

There is nothing wrong with this method.  But I'm looking for alternatives to evaluate.

---

**Inspired by Yakym Pirozhenko**

```
m, n = len(d1.columns), len(d2.columns)
lvl0 = np.repeat(np.arange(m), n)
lvl1 = np.tile(np.arange(n), m)
v1, v2 = d1.values, d2.values

pd.DataFrame(
    v1[:, lvl0] * v2[:, lvl1],
    d1.index,
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(d1.columns[lvl0], d2.columns[lvl1])))
)
```

However, this is a more clumsy implementation of numpy broadcasting which is better covered by Divakar.

**Timing**
All answers were good answers and demonstrate different aspects of pandas and numpy.  Please consider up-voting them if you found them useful and informative.

```
%%timeit
m, n = len(d1.columns), len(d2.columns)
lvl0 = np.repeat(np.arange(m), n)
lvl1 = np.tile(np.arange(n), m)
v1, v2 = d1.values, d2.values

pd.DataFrame(
    v1[:, lvl0] * v2[:, lvl1],
    d1.index,
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(d1.columns[lvl0], d2.columns[lvl1])))
)

%%timeit 
vals = (d2.values[:,None,:] * d1.values[:,:,None]).reshape(d1.shape[0],-1)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([d1.columns, d2.columns])
pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols, index=d1.index)

%timeit d1.apply(lambda x: d2.mul(x, axis=0).stack()).unstack()
%timeit pd.concat({x : d2.mul(d1[x], axis=0) for x in d1.columns}, axis=1)
%timeit pd.concat({(x, y): d1[x] * d2[y] for x, y in product(d1, d2)}, axis=1)

1000 loops, best of 3: 663 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 624 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.38 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 860 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop
```

Comment: The idea with `broadcasting` is to avoid the replications with `repeat/tile` as those would create intermediate arrays and `broadcasting` avoids those and that brings performance with it. So, one would see noticeable benefits when working with decent sized inputs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach with [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
vals = (d2.values[:,None,:] * d1.values[:,:,None]).reshape(d1.shape[0],-1)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([d1.columns, d2.columns])
df_out = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols, index=d1.index)
```

Sample run -

```
In [92]: d1
Out[92]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  1  2  3
4  2  3  4
5  3  4  5

In [93]: d2
Out[93]: 
   X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  0  0  1
4  1  0  0
5  0  1  0

In [110]: vals = (d2.values[:,None,:] * d1.values[:,:,None]).reshape(d1.shape[0],-1)
     ...: cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([d1.columns, d2.columns])
     ...: df_out = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols, index=d1.index)
     ...: 

In [111]: df_out
Out[111]: 
   A        B        C      
   X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0  2  0  0  3  0  0
1  0  2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0
2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0  0  5
3  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  0  3
4  2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0  0
5  0  3  0  0  4  0  0  5  0
```

Comment: This is actually what I've implemented in my production code... You took the bait (-:

Comment: @piRSquared Seemed like a bait. Was easy getting the values, not so much setting up the columns.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one-liner that uses pandas [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) method.
The "trick" is to use `stack`, so that the result of each computation within `apply` is a time series. Then use `unstack` to obtain the `Multiindex` form.

```
d1.apply(lambda x: d2.mul(x, axis=0).stack()).unstack()
```

Which gives:

```
     A              B              C          
     X    Y    Z    X    Y    Z    X    Y    Z
0  1.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0  0.0  5.0
3  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  3.0
4  2.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0  0.0
5  0.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0  0.0  5.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit vectorized version. There could be a better way.

```
In [846]: pd.concat({x : d2.mul(d1[x], axis=0) for x in d1.columns}, axis=1)
Out[846]:
   A        B        C
   X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0  2  0  0  3  0  0
1  0  2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0
2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0  0  5
3  0  0  1  0  0  2  0  0  3
4  2  0  0  3  0  0  4  0  0
5  0  3  0  0  4  0  0  5  0
```

Comment: Over my example data, it's definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the multi-index first, use it to obtain the shapes and multiply directly.

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [(c1, c2) for c1 in d1.columns for c2 in d2.columns])

a = d1.loc[:,cols.get_level_values(0)]
b = d2.loc[:,cols.get_level_values(1)]
a.columns = b.columns = cols

res = a * b
```

Comment: `ix` has been deprecated, but I like this concept.  Use `loc` instead.  I'm working on an improvement of this